# Problems creating a new user in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, command-line, adduser

I am experimenting with nginx+uswgi+Flask and am following [this tutorial](http://blog.kramerapps.com/post/22551999777/flask-uwsgi-nginx-ubuntu). However when I get to the portion for creating a new user for uswgi I am having troubles.

When I enter the command from the snippet the error I get is

```
$ sudo adduser -c 'uwsgi user,,,' -g nginx -d /nonexistent -s /bin/false uwsgi
Option g is ambiguous (gecos, gid, group)
Option d is ambiguous (debug, disabled-login, disabled-password)
Option s is ambiguous (shell, system)
...
```

I am by no means a ubuntu pro but after doing a little research I think the options I want are

```
$ sudo adduser -c 'uwsgi,,,' --group nginx --debug /nonexistent --system /bin/false uwsgi
```

however the error this returns is:

```
adduser: Only one or two names allowed.
```

here is my version information (if that helps)

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

So my question is what options should I be using to successfully create a uwsgi user such that I can complete the tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong command. Use `useradd` instead of `adduser`:

```
sudo useradd -c 'uwsgi user,,,' -g nginx -d /nonexistent -s /bin/false uwsgi
```

Comment: ```root@774f50a9ad03:~# adduser --version
adduser version 3.118

Adds a user or group to the system.

Copyright (C) 1997, 1998, 1999 Guy Maor <maor@debian.org>
Copyright (C) 1995 Ian Murdock <imurdock@gnu.ai.mit.edu>,
                   Ted Hajek <tedhajek@boombox.micro.umn.edu>```

https://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some examples from the net, like I did, it's easy to miss that some characters copied from web are not the valid characters in console (like dashes, quotes etc.) Here is a [blog post](http://www.freshblurbs.com/blog/2011/01/01/adduser-only-one-or-two-names-allowed.html) where I had found this clue (luckily for me)